# Error while downloading the source code of a page

Tags: c#, webclient

Good morning, 
A lot of posts have been made on this subject but none of them have worked.

I would like to retrieve the source code for this site : https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods

But it doesn't work; webclient returns the error: Error 403: Forbidden

Here's my code :

```
        string urlAddress = "https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods";

        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.DownloadString(urlAddress);
```

And here's what I tried:

```
        string urlAddress = "https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods";

        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.Headers.Add("User-Agent: Other");   // or client.Headers.Add("user-agent", " Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0");

        webClient.DownloadString(urlAddress);
```

--

```
            string urlAddress = "https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods";

        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            wc.CachePolicy = new System.Net.Cache.RequestCachePolicy(System.Net.Cache.RequestCacheLevel.BypassCache);
            wc.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            string result = wc.DownloadString(urlAddress);
        }
```

--

```
        string urlAddress = "https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods";

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(urlAddress);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

and still full of code.

Anyway, I really need a solution. 
If someone can help me, it would be cool :)

Comment: not directly answering your question, but WebClient is not recommended, Microsoft recommends to use HttpClient instead : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Either you have been blocked from accessing the site (probably because you tried to access it too many times), or you are not sending appropriate headers. Translate an HTTP request from Chrome or Fiddler into C# and try that.

Comment: Hi! I've been looking for an hour to find out how it works but I haven't found anything on the chrome side to get the source code for one page from one url and for the other, there's nothing, not even a documentation. A bit of code would be useful :)

Comment: edit: I installed filder and got a user agent that I put in the headers of my web client. It still doesn't work. `webClient.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36");`